# ValueError: bad input shape while evaluating performance using 1 feature with 3 column as target in dataset

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I am trying to implement SVR on linnerud dataset where I want to use only one feature from dataset i.e. chinup and target data to be considered is with all columns. But when I try to implement below code it gives me valueError. If someone could help me identify and correct the mistake it would be appreciable. Thanks

Below is what I have tried so far:

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import numpy as np


def loadDataset():
    ds = datasets.load_linnerud()
    X,y = ds.data, ds.target
    return X,y

def svmReg(data_list, y_list):
    data_list=data_list[:, np.newaxis, 0] #use chinup as feature
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(data_list, y_list, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)
    model=svm.SVR()
    model.fit(X_train,y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    print("SVM Mean squared error: %.2f"
          % mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
    return mse

data_list,y_list = loadDataset()
#print(data_list)
mse = svmReg(data_list, y_list)
```

I want to evaluate the performance so I am calculating mean squared error. Please correct me if this is incorrect way to evaluate the performance.

Refer the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Show the exact error you are getting.

Comment: your value error is bad input shape,because your y_train data has multiple columns

Comment: I have added the screenshot of error I am getting

Comment: While I think it *should* be possible to implement SVR with multiple output columns, I don't think libsvm has support for this. I also doubt that SVR makes a lot of sense when your X only has one column...